# Adding multiple JPanel to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

Alright so right now I have a JFrame which contains a JLayeredPane. So this runs a game GUI right now. I want to add buttons to side of this frame so that I can take in the inputs from the user through the buttons. 
Any ideas?

```
class mapGUI extends JFrame{
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    mapSize = new Dimension(mapColumn * 16 , mapRow * 16);

    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(mapSize);
    //Adding the layeredPane to the frame.
    getContentPane().add(layeredPane);

    //Adds the appropriate labels to the panels and adds them to the layeredPane.
    addPlayerPos();
    addDungeonItems();
    addDungeonFloor();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

This is the part of the code where I create the JFrame and add the JLayeredPane to it.

Comment: sorry no idea, nor ideas without posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue(s)

Comment: where do you want to add the buttons and how do you intend to use them?

Comment: *"is it better now?"*  It is *not* an SSCCE as @mKorbel suggested!

Comment: I want to add them to the right side. i want to add 5 buttons.

Answer (score 4):

1) don't use [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html), because has limitation up to 6. layers, use [JLayer (Java7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) based on `JXLayer` (Java6)

2) using [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) is about `setSize` / `setBounds`, that not confortable for resiziable `Container`

3) use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html),

4) or use [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

Comment: +1 for [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html). Also please correct me if I am wrong. The CardLayout cannot show multiple cards at a time so it should not be good for gaming where multiple layers are used.

Comment: @Nitin Chhajer correct, you are right, maybe I'm wrong (I used JLayeredPane only for UIManagers hacks) but I think that hard to use JLayeredPane for game, (correct me anyone about rendering isses) this is reason why JLayer is there ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Buttons through out the game you can use a BorderLayout and put the buttons on East/West of the layout, and add a LayeredPane to the Centre. If the buttons needs to overlap with the game screen you can use `layeredPaneObj.add(buttonPanel,new Integer(0))` this will keep the panel on the top.

Comment: @JakubZaverka please read the question. "_add buttons to side of this frame_" not **top** of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn basic stuff about [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) first.
As mentioned before, have a special look at the BorderLayout for your requirements